# EntityFramework Code First One to Many

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I would like to ask you how with this code create EntityFramework relation One to Many?

I need to have relation one companies can have many user. With this code as I shown below

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Ideo.Mvc.Data.Model.Core
{
public class FirmyValue : Entity
{
    public string Nazwa { get; set; }
    public string NIP { get; set; }
    public string Adres { get; set; }
}

internal class FirmyValueMappings : EntityTypeConfiguration<FirmyValue>
{
    public FirmyValueMappings()
    {
        Property(p => p.Nazwa).HasMaxLength(200);
        Property(p => p.NIP).HasMaxLength(200);
        Property(p => p.Adres).HasMaxLength(200);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: here-> http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: How does `FirmyValue` relate to "one companies many user"? Is a `FirmyValue` a company? What does your user model look like if so?

Comment: Thank you I've got the answer